# "No such file or directory" error when calling fc-list in python

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess

I am attempting to scrape a terminal window of the list of fonts installed on the curent hosting server. I have written the following code:

```
 import subprocess
 cmd = 'fc-list'
 output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE ).communicate()[0]
```

but when i call this code, an exception is raised:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I can open a terminal window, and this works fine. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) recommend to pass a sequence instead of a string. Could you try with a list: `cmd = ['fc-list']` ?

Comment: I just attempted this, with the same exception result

Comment: I am running on OSX for development, but hosting on Unbuntu linux. I found that I had to provide the whole path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the absolute path to the executable.  When you open a terminal window you then have a shell running which will search in $PATH to find the program.  When you run the program directly, via subprocess, you do not have a shell to search $PATH.  (note: it is possible to tell subprocess that you do want a shell, but usually this leads to security vulnerabilities)

Here is what you would want to use:

```
 import subprocess
 cmd = '/usr/local/bin/fc-list'
 output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE ).communicate()[0]
```

Comment: yeah, I just figured this out: /opt/X11/bin/fc-list